# How does the graphic inside a Javafx ListCell catch MouseEvents?

Tags: javafx

I have a custom ListCell with a ImageView as the graphic. I want this ImageView to catch MouseEvents (like mouse_over, or mouse_click). But it does not catch any events.
The custom ListCell however catches events.

Is this unusual behaviour or do I need to pass the Events from the ListCell to its graphic (somehow)?
If I add a Button, it gets Mouseevents, strangely.
If you have just a link of a working example, I would happily crawl my way through it ;)
Thanks for your effort.

Class CustomCell:

```
package test;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;

public class CustomCell extends ListCell<String>{
    ImageView removeTrack;

public CustomCell(){
    removeTrack = new ImageView("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lbN1Ca63JPs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAQ/smvshnyosS4/s46-c-k/photo.jpg");
    removeTrack.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        System.out.println("test");
    });
}

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String t, boolean bln) {
        super.updateItem(t, bln);
        if (t != null) {
            setText(t);
            setGraphic(removeTrack);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
            addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    removeTrack.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
            addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    removeTrack.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Main-Class:

```
package test;


import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class JAVAtest extends Application{

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     launch(args);

 }

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    ObservableList<String> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
              "Julia", "Ian", "Sue", "Matthew", "Hannah", "Stephan", "Denise");
    ListView lv = new ListView(names);
    lv.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>(){

        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> p) {
             return new CustomCell();
        }
    });
    Scene scene = new Scene(lv);



    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}


}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. I can't see why your code isn't working. Seems like a bug.

It works fine if you wrap the image view in a container of some kind. For example:

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class CustomCell extends ListCell<String> {
    ImageView removeTrack;
    StackPane imageContainer ;

    public CustomCell() {
        removeTrack = new ImageView(
                "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lbN1Ca63JPs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAQ/smvshnyosS4/s46-c-k/photo.jpg");
        removeTrack.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            System.out.println("test");
        });
        imageContainer = new StackPane(removeTrack);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String t, boolean bln) {
        super.updateItem(t, bln);
        if (t != null) {
            setText(t);
            setGraphic(imageContainer);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
            addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    imageContainer.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
            addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    imageContainer.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
        } else {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }

}
```

(As an aside: *always* handle all possible cases in the `updateItem(...)` method. Your code will have bugs if you start removing items or possibly while scrolling, because you don't handle the empty cell / null item case.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works great.
I don't know why the StackPane is necessary, but this is good enough for me.
Also thanks for the "aside", always happy to get a better programmer.